# Regarding AWS Lambda function to trigger SNS function repeatedly once alarm is triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I am new to AWS Lambda function . I need to get some work done on AWS Lambda

As well know AWS Cloudwatch will trigger a particular alarm if it breaches the threshold but it will give one time SNS notification for breaching but suppose if cpu utilization remains above 70 percent for 1 hour , we won't get any notification in cloud watch alarm , the next time we will get the notification will only be when cpu utilization comes back to below threshold state .

So was put helping hands so if someone can help me in writing a lambda function that will trigger SNS repeatedly till  every 5 minutes till the CPU utilization is avbove the threshold value

Regards
John

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good use of [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions). With step functions you can loop with a delay. Each loop could check to see if the alarm is still above threshold and if it is it can call your function again. You'd need a second lambda to check the state of the alarm.